# "Call to undefined function post_image_thumbnail()" Error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I recently changed my WordPress theme. I have a custom page template that I am trying to move over to the new theme, but the custom page template is now throwing an error.

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function `post_image_thumbnail()` in [link to custom page url] on line 55

I thought it might be the child theme not supporting thumbnails, so I added this to the child theme's `functions.php`:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

But it didn't solve anything.

Could someone help debug my code? Maybe I have a syntax error that I can't see?

```
<h3><?php echo get_cat_name(26);?></h3>
<?php query_posts(array('category__and'=>array(75,26),'meta_key'=>'wpcf-sortname','orderby'=>'meta_value','order'=>ASC,'posts_per_page' => -1));if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><div class="indentlist"><?php post_image_thumbnail(); ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="participants"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div><?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old theme contained a function that your new theme doesn't. The content you've moved from the old theme to the new one calls the missing function resulting in an error.

Your best course of action would be to move the missing function to your new theme. It may prove more difficult than a simple copy/paste.

An alternative would be to replace `post_image_thumbnail();` in the code you posted with `the_post_thumbnail( 'SIZE' );`. Change `'SIZE'` to a valid image size name. Options you could try include `'large'` and `'full'`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try both those options.

Comment: I copied over the functions.php code that applied to the thumbnails and it is working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

in archive-product.php I add the following code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I found this in the woocommerce page, because the other code is for the image for post I understand, but this no functions,

thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, but I didn't found the answer.

I would like to put an image thumbnail at woocommerce category page. For this, I add the following code at `taxonomy-product_cat.php`:

```
/* indicar thumbnail category product */
if ( has_category_thumbnail() ) {
  the_category_thumbnail();
}else{
echo '<img alt="Imagen por defecto" src="#"; />';
}
```

I also add in the `functions.php` this code:

```
add_theme_support('category-thumbnails');
```

I put in the admin wp on the woocommerce page category an image for thumbnail, but the following error is in the woo category page:

Call to undefined function `has_category_thumbnail()`